# File not downloading from url in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class DownloadTask {

    private static final String TAG = "Download Task";
    private Context context;

    private String downloadUrl = "", downloadFileName = "";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public DownloadTask(Context context, String downloadUrl) {
        this.context = context;

        this.downloadUrl = downloadUrl;


        downloadFileName = downloadUrl.substring(downloadUrl.lastIndexOf( '/' ),downloadUrl.length());//Create file name by picking download file name from URL
        Log.e(TAG, downloadFileName);

        //Start Downloading Task
        new DownloadingTask().execute();
    }

    private class DownloadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        File apkStorage = null;
        File outputFile = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            try {
                if (outputFile != null) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Downloaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    }, 3000);

                    Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed" +e);
                //Change button text if exception occurs

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                }, 3000);
                Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed with Exception - " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            }


            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);//Create Download URl
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//Open Url Connection
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");//Set Request Method to "GET" since we are grtting data
                c.connect();//connect the URL Connection

                //If Connection response is not OK then show Logs
                if (c.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Server returned HTTP " + c.getResponseCode()
                            + " " + c.getResponseMessage());

                }


                //Get File if SD card is present
    /*if (new CheckForSDCard().isSDCardPresent()) {

                    apkStorage = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                                    + "NKDROID FILES");
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Oops!! There is no SD Card.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/


                //If File is not present create directory
                if (!apkStorage.exists()) {
                    apkStorage.mkdir();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Directory Created.");
                }

                outputFile = new File(apkStorage, downloadFileName);//Create Output file in Main File

                //Create New File if not present
                if (!outputFile.exists()) {
                    outputFile.createNewFile();
                    Log.e(TAG, "File Created");
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);//Get OutputStream for NewFile Location

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();//Get InputStream for connection

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];//Set buffer type
                int len1 = 0;//init length
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);//Write new file
                }

                //Close all connection after doing task
                fos.close();
                is.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                //Read exception if something went wrong
                e.printStackTrace();
                outputFile = null;
                Log.e(TAG, "Download Error Exception " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have done the following coding to download a file from a url... But when I run the app it stucks on the downloading screen... I am trying to download the file in the internal storage... I have tried every possible way to download the from ur;l... If anyone can suggests any changes int he above code or anyother code sequence I can use...

Comment: idk if it help you but i have made a java download manager before, i put link here so you check if you wanted : https://github.com/Amirhossein-Hediehloo/Java-Download-Manager

Comment: Thanks for that.. But I can't include your whole program in my coding.. So can you guide me on the above thing...

Comment: can you give some more details, for example what do you mean from "it stucks on the downloading screen" do you mean it freezes and you cant interact with UI? or any exceptions you get

Comment: It just keeps on loading... The UI is stable I can back and try again but still no fucntion.. It again starts downloading and remains there...

Comment: If you can suggest anything else which can let me download from a url and store it in the internal storage of android....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's the problem with your code.. But you can use the following steps to solve your problem.... Just open your pdf url in android chrome... The code is mentioned below....

```
 try {
                    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                    i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
                    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("your pdf url"));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // Chrome is not installed
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("your pdf url"));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
```